# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value') for a input within a form

Tags: reactjs, graphql, next.js, apollo-client

I am trying to do a mutation to add a new item into my Postgres database via Apollo GraphQL. I am following the documentation for a form/component that submits a new product into a query.

I am receiving an error on the `input.value` with it being a property that cannot be read. This is within the form and is within the bold bracket. Any help on how to fix this would be great!

```js
import type { NextPage } from 'next'
import Head from 'next/head'
import {Card} from "../components/Card"
//import {products} from "../data/products";
import {gql, useQuery, useMutation} from "@apollo/client"
import { useState } from 'react';

const AllProductQuery = gql`
  query Product_Query {
    products {
      title
      description
    }
  }
  
`;

const AddProducts = gql`
  mutation Add_Product($title: String!
                      $description: String!
  ) {
    product(description: $description, title: $title) {
      id
      description
      title
    }
  }
`;

function AddProductForm():JSX.Element {
  let input:any;

  const [addProduct, {data, loading, error}] = useMutation(AddProducts)
  
  return (

    <form className='flex flex-col p-2' onSubmit={(e) => {
      e.preventDefault(); 
      addProduct({variables: {title: input.value}})
      input.value=''

    }}>
      <input  placeholder="Title" type='text' ref={(node) => (node = input)} required/>
      <input placeholder="Description" type='text' ref={(node) => (node = input)} required/>
      <button type="submit" className='bg-blue-500 text-white rounded-lg'>Submit</button>
    </form>    
  )
}

const Home: NextPage = () => {
  const {data, error, loading} = useQuery(AllProductQuery);
  
  if (loading) {return <p>Loading...</p>}
  if(error) {return <p>{error.message}</p>}

  return (
    
    <div >
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
        <div className='container mx-auto my-20 px-5 '>
        {data.products.map((product: any) => (
          <Card key={product.id} title={product.title} description={product.description}  />          
        ))}
        </div>    
        <AddProductForm />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

Comment: You delcare the `input` variable with `let input:any;` but never assign a value to it. When you try accessing it with `input.value` it'll throw the error you see because `input` is not defined.

Comment: Did you mean to assign the title input's ref to `input`, i.e. `ref={(node) => (input = node)}`? You're currently doing the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `ref` attribute wrong, you have to use `useRef` hook like below, in order to access dom elements (here input tag).

here is what you need:

```
//...
import { useState, useRef } from "react";
//...
function AddProductForm(): JSX.Element {
  const titleRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const descriptionRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  const [addProduct, { data, loading, error }] = useMutation(AddProducts);

  return (
    <form
      className="flex flex-col p-2"
      onSubmit={(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        addProduct({ variables: { title: titleRef.current.value } });
        titleRef.current.value = "";
        //you can also do something with the descriptionRef
      }}
    >
      <input
        placeholder="Title"
        type="text"
        ref={titleRef}
        required
      />
      <input
        placeholder="Description"
        type="text"
        ref={descriptionRef}
        required
      />
      <button type="submit" className="bg-blue-500 text-white rounded-lg">
        Submit
      </button>
    </form>
  );
}
//...
```

Comment: I am now running into an error of: Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Response not successful: Received status code 400

Comment: @Esore That's a different issue, most likely related to your `addProduct` mutation. Shouldn't you be passing a `description` field to `addProduct`, i.e. `addProduct({ variables: { title: titleRef.current.value, description: descriptionRef.current.value }})`?

Comment: Yes I added the description field to it. ```onSubmit={(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        addProduct({ variables: { title: titleRef.current.value, description: descriptionRef.current.value} });
        titleRef.current.value = "";
        descriptionRef.current.value = "";``` Could this also be related to how my resolver is built out? That is the only thing left that I could think of.